# Time Derivative of quantum moment of inertia

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, moment-of-inertia, time-evolution

The moment of inertia is given as in terms of the wave function

$I=\frac{m}{2}\int d\textbf{r}r^2|\psi|^2 $

The time derivative of it is basically
$\dot{I}=\frac{m}{2}\int d\textbf{r}r^2 \partial_t(\psi\psi^*)$

I understand that if we apply the schrodinger equation $i\hbar\partial_t\psi = H\psi$, and its conjugate version we can obtain

$\dot{I}=-\frac{im}{2\hbar}\int d\textbf{r}r^2 (\psi^*H\psi-\psi H\psi^*)$

but I couldnt understand how we reach

$$\dot{I}=-\frac{im}{2\hbar}\int d\textbf{r}\psi^*[r^2,H]\psi.$$

Above the square bracket means commutator $[A,B] = AB-BA$.

Comment: Do you have a reference for defining the moment of inertia in QM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The integral notation is just obscuring what's going on. Let's write
$$\langle \phi,\psi\rangle = \int \phi(\mathbf{r})^\ast \psi(\mathbf{r})\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}$$
more abstractly for the inner product. Then
$$ I = \frac{m}{2}\langle \psi, \hat{r}^2\psi\rangle$$
and consequently
$$ \dot{I} = -\frac{\mathrm{i}m}{2}\left(\langle \psi,\hat{r}^2 \hat{H}\psi\rangle - \langle \hat{H}\psi, \hat{r}^2\psi\rangle\right) = -\frac{\mathrm{i}m}{2}\left(\langle \psi,\hat{r}^2 \hat{H}\psi\rangle - \langle \psi, \hat{H}\hat{r}^2\psi\rangle \right), $$
since $H$ is self-adjoint. The r.h.s. is now obviously
$$ \dot{I} = -\frac{\mathrm{i}m}{2}\langle \psi, [\hat{r}^2, \hat{H}]\psi\rangle.$$